# if statements in while loops

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am new to programming, and I am trying to practice various functions with a simple "Pick a Number" application. However I have ran into a problem.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int deNumero = rnd.Next(1,100001);
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pick a number 1 - 100000");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int numero = Int32.Parse(input);
    if(numero < deNumero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lower");
    }
    else if(numero > deNumero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Higher");
    }
    else if(numero == deNumero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Well done!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What?");
    }
}
```

Let's say I pick a number that is greater than `deNumero` and it prints "Lower". Where I am seeing a problem is when I pick the number 1, it will print "Lower" again. it keeps going to the same `if` statement even when it shouldn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you pick a number greater than deNumero, it will always print "Higher".  You might have your higher and lower logic inverted.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the first `if` statement and step through your program.

Comment: You have `(numero < deNumero)` which returns `Console.WriteLine("Lower")` I think if numero is lower than deNumero, you need to return `"Higher"`.. Assuming you are telling the person to input a "higher" number and vice versa for `(numero > deDumero)` should return `"Lower"`

Comment: Try adding `Console.WriteLine(numero);` after the `int numero = Int32.Parse(input);` line. This will help rule out the parsing of input as the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All your code working correct you can see result, I print your DeNumero to see or put break point in you if statement to figure out what is heppening:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
        int deNumero = rnd.Next(1, 100001);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DeNomero:{0}", deNumero);
            Console.WriteLine("Pick a number 1 - 100000");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int numero = Int32.Parse(input);
            if (numero < deNumero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lower");
            }
            else if (numero > deNumero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Higher");
            }
            else if (numero == deNumero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Well done!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What?");
            }
        }
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program and found it works, watch out you set the random number range 1 to 100,000, not 1-10,000.. and are you sure you know the value of deNumero?